# How to determine the changes in device contacts in phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, contacts

I have an application which sync contacts from device contact manager and i have done it successfully now i want to synchronize the contacts which has been modified in my device contact manager to my app.

I didn't find any plugin for this to get the information of contacts which has been modified,updated or added contact so that i can sync that particular contact in my app.

The worst scenario is to again fetch all contacts and compare each contacts and their fields for any changes.

Please suggest some good solution so that i can implement it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method would have been to fire a "Trigger" from the Contacts DataBase when user modified/added data to it. However, this is out of scope as Contacts is a different application all together and it does not expose any API/Mechanism to meet this requirement.

So you will have to manually match your app's and Contacts App's DB.

But I do believe maintaining the Copy of Contacts in your app is needless effort. You can do away with this issue of data inconsistency management by simply using the Contacts DB as such.

If you want to manage some additional information about contacts in your app, then you can use the ID of Contacts DB as a Foreign Key in your App's Database. If you re-structure your database this way, I guess you can overcome the need to handle contacts modification.

Comment: Yeah i have used similar kind of approach by maintaining the copy of contact database at my end and each time the application opens i will check for any updates happened in the phonebook contacts.